# Would I need JWT authentication if I have the CSRF in place?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, backend, csrf

This is the reverse of the usual question asked if CSRF is required along with JWT. Here, We have CSRF already in place for cross site forgery protection but unable to decide if I should have the JWT too for API Authentication. Will CSRF work for both - Cross site protection and API authentication ?

Comment: This cannot be answerer because it lacks details. The "default" answer would be no, the purpose is very different, and a csrf token is not suitable for authentication. However, depending on how you issue csrf tokens, what exactly is included and how you manage it on the client, you might find that simply referring to it as an auth token is fine for your usecase and also protects against csrf. But note that this is not necessarily the case, nor the best practice. It might just happen to be like that under special circumstances.

Comment: Hi @GaborLengyel  This is how the XSRF is implemented at the moment. It starts generating the token once the user lands on the page. The token is sent as the session starts even before the login and with each subsequent request, the token is refreshed and sent as response to be used along with the next request. Should I generate the tokens after the login or leave as it it. And if I implement after login CSRF tokens, will it eliminate the need of JWT. Sorry If I am still not very clear but I tried max I could be.